# Batch script does not get the return value from exe file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to use batch script to start two exe file. The script should red the output (return value) of the first exe program1 and if the return value is "0" then should execute another exe program2, else if the return value of the first exe program1 is "1" then should not, just execute first program1. I have a script but its never jump to the second exe program 2 in case of "0". Any help ? Here the script

```
REM for every file do:
for %%a in (*.*) do (   
  REM get last line [reference filename with %%a]
  for /f %%b in ('C:\program1.exe -a -b -c "%%~a"') do set lastLine=%%b
  REM check for "0":
   if "!lastLine!"=="0" (
    REM call with filename as parameter:
    call :dothis "%%~a"
  ) else (
    echo %%a nothing to do
  )
)
goto :eof

:dothis
REM execute second program with filename as parameter:
start C:\Program2.exe %1
goto :eof
```

Comment: Return value or output? It matters a great deal.

Comment: ok .  So the exe file is OpenCV program to detect object. So if successful detect object the OpenCV program1 should have output 1 if not then output 0.  in the program Im using cout. Its C++ OpenCV program so based on if detected of not object I would like to call another OpenCV program

Comment: ok .  So the exe file is OpenCV program to detect object. So if successful detect object the OpenCV program1 should have output 1 if not then output 0.  in the program Im using cout. Its C++ OpenCV program so based on if detected or not an object in OpenCv program1 I would like to call another OpenCV program2. Hope more clear now

Comment: If this is the total script, you are missing `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` in the beginning of it.

Comment: Im not familiar with batch script. Thats the all I have.  So I need the whole script code to solve my problem. Please  could you post the all script code that works?

Answer (score 0):

You pass a var in parentheses to `:dothis` and start uses the first argument in parentheses as the window title, so Program2 doesn't get any args.

```
:dothis
REM execute second program with filename as parameter:
start "" "C:\Program2.exe" %1
```